# Are token elements required in MathML?

Tags: mathml

As the question title states, is it okay to write just

```
<math>a <msup>x 2</msup> + b x + c</math>
```

or do you really need to write

```
<math>
  <mrow>
    <mi>a</mi> <mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo> <msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup>
    <mo>+</mo><mi>b</mi><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>x</mi>
    <mo>+</mo><mi>c</mi>
  </mrow>
</math>
```

As far as Firefox goes it doesn't render a

> Invalid Markup

error, but that hardly means other browser might not in the future if the spec actually prohibits it officially.

Answer (score 0):

> As the question title states, is it okay to write just
>
> ```
> <math>a <msup>x 2</msup> + b x + c</math>
> ```

**No**, it isn't.

> do you really need to write
>
> ```
> <math>
>   <mrow>
>     <mi>a</mi> <mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo> <msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup>
>     <mo>+</mo><mi>b</mi><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>x</mi>
>     <mo>+</mo><mi>c</mi>
>   </mrow>
> </math>
> ```

**Yes**, see http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML3/chapter2.html#fund.syntax.

> As far as Firefox goes it doesn't render a "Invalid Markup" error, but that hardly means other browser might not in the future if the spec actually prohibits it officially.

At the begin browsers render a "Invalid Markup" error for anything that doesn't follow the spec. Today browsers try to correct the markup. For example

```
<p>
<ul>
<li>foo</li>
<li>bar</li>
</ul>
<p>
```

is invalid since you need to use

```
<p></p>
<ul>
<li>foo</li>
<li>bar</li>
</ul>
<p></p>
```

but no browser will stop rendering the page because of it.

Comment: You might want to link to the MathML spec to substantiate the simple "yes".

Comment: Yeah, I read through the spec, but I just wasn't sure whether it specified somewhere how cases should be handled where a token isn't used or not. Honestly, I have an extremely hard time figuring out what point those tokens serve... I mean, how hard is to realize that a number is a number if it's not wrapped in a `<mn>`... it's not like complex numbers or something are considered numbers, it's really just plain old numbers... :S

Comment: You need `<mn>` because that MathML cover presentation and content markup. I recommend https://11011110.livejournal.com/314841.html to understand why you need `<mn>1</mn>` instead of `1` but the long story short is that MathML was design to handle the case where `1` is a operator and `X` is the roman number "10" instead of a variable, vector, matrix, operator, ...

Answer (score 0):

MathML is intended for mathematics presentation markup. It is aimed to provide all information needed for correctly typesetting a mathematical formula.

In mathematical typesetting, identifiers (or, simply "variables"), operators and numbers are typeset differently. There are a lot of subtle differences, but to name a few: identifiers are normally *italic* style (and use a mathematical serif font), whereas numbers are roman style. Operators use subtle spacing rules on either side. These are just a few examples.

As presentation MathML is not intended to describe the meaning of a formula, merely how it **looks**, all this information must be encoded in the markup. The MathML renderer does **not** interpret the formula, either. It looks at the markup and renders accordingly.

Authoring MathML directly is not easy, and, in fact, it is mostly done programmatically, rather than inputting directly. If you need a more straightforward way, try ASCIImath or LaTeX. A renderer like MathJax renders those as well.